# Electron app: can't find where keyboard shortcut is registered

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm new to electron apps, and I'm attempting to modify an open source electron app.

Here is the repo for the app I want to modify:

https://github.com/microsoft/VoTT

Specifically, I want to change what happens when Ctrl(+Alt or Shift)+Arrow key is pressed. I've found where most keyboard shortcuts are registered, but not this one. The app doesn't appear to use global shortcuts.

Are there any other methods of registering a shortcut I should be looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing a project-wide search on `arrowDown` and leaving out `README.md` gives me 2 files: `src\registerToolbar.ts` and `src\react\components\common\tagInput\tagInputToolbar.tsx`. Same search on `arrowUp` gives an extra file: `src\react\components\common\keyboardManager\keyboardRegistrationManager.test.ts`. Have you looked at these ?

Comment: `src\react\components\common\assetPreview\videoAsset.tsx` has `arrowLeft` and `arrowRight` definitions